# Finance Report Template

Tags: templates, report

I am trying to put together a LaTeX template that mirrors the following [equity research report](http://www.mauldineconomics.com/images/uploads/overmyshoulder/Goldman_Sachs_-_US_Equity_Outlook.pdf). Does anyone have any recommendations for similar templates that can be my starting code?

Comment: I have no direct template, but would recommend you to have a look at a KOMA class such as `scrartcl`. You can customize nearly the whole layout. The large left margin is a task of `geometry`.  The figure and caption styles are probably also easy to imitate. Please make a first attempt on your own and ask specific questions with some code. Then it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: BTW For the plots: TikZ and PGFplots.

Comment: I've made good progress with the article class: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353066/90121

Comment: If you now split your problem into smaller pieces as we appreciate it you should consider deleting this question.

Comment: Right now, the question is too broad or a *do it for me question*. A [more specific question has been posted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353066/grey-sidebar-with-article-class-tikz#). I vote to close as duplicate, although it is not a duplicate technically.